# NCover 1.5.8 does generate coverate report

Tags: .net, testdriven.net, ncover

I run NCoverExploler, configure it, so command line look like this

```
"D:\Development\Projects\t.net\lib\NCover\NCover.Console.exe" //reg //w "D:\Development\Projects\t.net\build_output\t.net" //v "D:\Development\Projects\t.net\lib\NUnit\nunit-console.exe" t.Core.Tests.dll /framework=4.0
```

Output coverage.xml appears to be empty. In the same time, if I run Coverate report by Visual Studio (by TestDriven.Net), it generates just perfectly.

I've compared coverage.log files for 2 cases. In case if I run by NCoverExporer:

> EVENT:   Log link established.
>   EVENT:   Communications link established.
>   MESSAGE: Ready for command input.
>   EVENT:   Verbose Logging Disabled
>   EVENT:   Logging Enabled
>   EVENT:   AutoExclusion Enabled
>   MESSAGE: Monitoring Assemblies: (All Loaded Assemblies)
>   MESSAGE: Excluding Types and Methods with these Attributes: CoverageExcludeAttribute;
>   MESSAGE: Received driver ready event.
>   MESSAGE: v2.0.50727

In case of TestDriven.net

> EVENT:   Log link established.
>   EVENT:   Communications link established.
>   MESSAGE: Ready for command input.
>   EVENT:   Verbose Logging Disabled
>   EVENT:   Logging Enabled
>   EVENT:   AutoExclusion Enabled
>   MESSAGE: Monitoring Assemblies: Microsoft.Web.Mvc;Moq;T.Core;T.Core.Tests;Web;
>   MESSAGE: Excluding Types and Methods with these Attributes: CoverageExcludeAttribute;System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute;
>   MESSAGE: Received driver ready event.
>   MESSAGE: v4.0.30319

Please see the difference in Monitoring Assemblies and MESSAGE: v4.0.30319. In case of TD.net, it correctly supples .NET framework.

Any clues, how to make NCover make work, as it in TD.net ? Where is it configured?

Comment: Anyone met something similar ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.  Did you ever mange to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Sam.. no I left it as unresolved..

Comment: did you see my answer?  I was able to get this working...

Comment: @Sam, thanks a lot for this.. thanks a lot for notification, as well! the issue is not high priority to me now.. I just do my coverage with td.net. But will get to try you suggestion, as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the answer I found here:  [Force NCover 1.5.8 to use v4 framework like testdriven.net does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4921443/97614).

I also made all programs run with .net 4 using the other answer to that question, but don't know if that was important or not.  I'll investigate and update the answer.

I have updated my answer in the other thread with the solution which I was able to use to get things up and running on my (win 7 x64) machine.  Hopefully it will help you, I now get the `MESSAGE: v4.0.30319` in my coverage.log.

Answer (score 0):

NCover 1.5.8 Does not support .net 4.0 and it looks like TD.NET is picking up .NET 4 as the default.

Comment: don't really get this? If NCover does not support it, how it works in TD.net ?

Comment: It must be compiling the code as .net 2 code and running it that way. 1.5.8 only supports the .net 2.0 profiler api.

Comment: its true that 1.5.8 only supports the .net 2.0 profiler api, but its possible to make the .net 4.0 apps interact with the .net 2.0 profiler api.  no guarantees about success, but the solution in the linked question in the other answer worked for me.